# how to seperate variables into different views to fit my mvc

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, view, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am trying to separate variables into different views before I put them into `Laravel` controllers...so my question is what is the best way to achieve this , how would I separate my `$body`, `$logo`,`$nav` variables into different classes in a case like this ? Thanks in advance!

my current view file

```
$body = array();
switch(Page::$display_mode) {
case 'one':
...
$body[] = array();
$logo[] = array();
$nav[] = array();
...
case 'two':
...
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Maybe try to explain better and why you want this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to do that ? You could just use blade template and include them in an index page or main page.